# Best approach for dual-state Action

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, action

I have recently implemented an `Action` that toggles the enabled status of a business function.  Whenever the user invokes the action I set a boolean flag: "*willEnable*" to determine whether the next invocation will enable or disable the function.  Likewise I update the action name, short description and icon to reflect the new state.  Then within my `actionPerformed(...)` method I take a different action based on the state of `willEnable`.

1. Is this the correct approach or can
   anyone recommend a better one (as I
   suspect this is a common problem)? 
   (I can see that `JToggleButton` acts
   as a two-state button but I want
   this Action to be visible on a
   `JMenuBar` as well as a `JButton`,
   so do not think this is
   appropriate).

**EDIT**

Specifically, how do applications like IDEA deal with this?  Would they use multi-state actions (as above) or would they swap a **different `Action`** into a given `JButton` using `setAction(Action)`?  Perhaps this approach is better?

2. When updating an action's properties
   can I rely on GUI components
   initialised with that `Action` (e.g.
   `JButton`) automatically repainting
   themselves?  What if the `JButton`
   size changes as a result?  Should I
   be revalidating the containing
   `JPanel` myself?
3. Is changing the action's name a bad
   thing to do?  This is the only way I
   can make the JButton text change, but am concious that the name should probably remain constant if the action is being placed in an `ActionMap`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect that any GUI component which is created with some data "model" (I would include an `Action` as a data model) should register itself as a listener to that model. It *must* take appropriate, erm, action on a `PropertyChangeEvent` being fired: any other behaviour would constitute a bug in my opinion.

The questionable thing here is whether it is legitimate to change the name of the action; I think that *it is not legitimate*. Your action logically is **ToggleEnabledStatus** and that does not change because the action has been invoked. Any component which needs to display any other text should register itself as a listener to the `Action` and then check your `willEnable` flag to take the appropriate, erm, action.

Alternately you could write your own class which implemented `ToggleButtonModel` and `Action` at the same time and controlled the change events from within it. This is a lot of code, however, for such little benefit

Comment: This is what I thought (regarding not changing the action name).  However, this means I need to explicitly set my JButton text to "Enable XYZ" or "Disable XYZ" each time the action is "toggled", as JButton uses the Action name as text by default.  The alternative would be to use two different Actions and call setAction on the JButton each time.  Not sure if this is better or worse ...

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at the [State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).

Basically, you create an interface and two (or more) implementations of it for each state. As a simple example, the disable state might just implement the interface to do nothing while the enabled state does some actions. To switch state you would simply do

```
interface IState {
  void doAction();
  boolean isEnabled();
}

class EnabledState implement IState {
  void doAction() {
    setState(new DisabledState());
    // do something
  }
  boolean isEnabled() {return true;}
}

class DisabledState implement IState {
  void doAction() {
    setState(new EnabledState());
    // do nothing
  }
  boolean isEnabled() {return false;}
}

private IState state = new DisabledState(); // default is disabled
private PropertyChangeSupport support = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

void setState(IState state) {
  if (this.state != state) {
    IState oldState = this.state;
    this.state = state;
    support.firePropertyChange("enabled", oldState.isEnabled(), state.isEnabled());
  }
}

void doAction() {
  state.doAction();
}
```

While it is a little overhead for a single method, it certainly pays of as soon as you have several methods that change it's behavior depending on a single state.

Comment: Thanks - Yes I could consider this although TBH the logic run based on the value of willEnable is only 1-2 lines of code anyway.  I'm more concerned about whether there's a better solution in dealing with the UI-related side-effects of the state change, and whether there's an idiomatic approach of dealing with this problem when you have multiple "actions" based off one button.

Comment: It's a long time since I've last done Swing, but can't you use the observer pattern to notify any GUI components of state changes in your controller?

Comment: Well I could use PropertyChangeListener (I'd recommend avoiding Observer) to detect changes in the Action, and then revalidate the JPanel.  I'm just not sure if it's required.

Comment: I said "observer pattern" not observer. `PropertyChangeListener` (and all the other listeners) follow the observer pattern. And looking at the Javadoc for `javax.swing.Action.addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener)` seems to prove me right: "When its enabled state or other property changes, the registered listeners are informed of the change". So your button should implement `PropertyChangeListener` and listen for changes of the enabled state.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought (re. the JButton listening for changes).  However, I'm not sure if the containing JPanel will ... I would hope so.